# Have to press enter two times to search

Tags: html, css

I have made this search box, but you have to press enter twice to search, any help?

```css
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('frmSearch').onsubmit = function() {
        window.location = 'http://www.google.com/search?q= ' + document.getElementById('txtSearch').value;
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

```html
<form id="frmSearch" class="search2" method="get" action="default.html" />
<input class="search2" id="txtSearch" type="text" name="serach_bar" onclick="myFunction()" placeholder="Search..." size="31" maxlength="500"       
value="" style="left: 500px; top: 153px; width: 293px; height: 26px;" />
```

Comment: can you provide your `form` full html

Comment: That's an invalid code. Form is prematurely closed.

Comment: @PraveenKumar No it isn't. It just has an error in the form's start tag. I'd be more concerned about the typo in the input name, and the `left` and `top` in the input style that don't do anything.

Comment: @MrLister Okay, not error syntactically. It is invalid by behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

You made an error in the form tag. Change this:

```
<form />
<input />
```

Into this:

```
<form>
<input />
</form>
```

Form is not a self-closing tag: http://xahlee.info/js/html5_non-closing_tag.html. You should close the form after the input(s).

Working example here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/apoYmm